# Cloud Vision API - PDF+OCR as Output Format Possible?

Tags: pdf, output, ocr

Is it Possible to OCR PDF, and output the Text in the PDF (Text Under Image). 
Instead of an seperate file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

First convert the google cloud vision response to a hocr file using [gcv2hocr](https://github.com/dinosauria123/gcv2hocr).

```
gcv2hocr test.jpg.json output.hocr
```

Then use [hocr-tools](https://github.com/tmbdev/hocr-tools) to stitch the hocr data to the pdf file.

```
hocr-pdf --savefile out.pdf <imgdir>
```